# Кликнуть по li элементу

Tags: javascript, html

Как через консоль кликнуть по li элементу в TelegramWeb, что бы выбрался чат?

Пробовал `document.getElementsByClassName('im_dialog_wrap')[0].click()`

и `document.getElementsByClassName('im_dialog_wrap')[0].getElementsByClassName('im_dialog')[0].click()`, но безрезультатно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы симулировать клик

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```

Потом первый аргументом передай элемент li

```
eventFire(document.getElementById('mytest1'), 'click');
```

Comment: Результатов нет

Comment: Значит неправильно указываете элемент, в том месте где я своровал функцию у ребят все работало)